# Modulus of complex number squared

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I need to proof the following statement.
Show that for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $|\lambda|^2 = \lambda\bar{\lambda}$.
Could someone help me how to proof this? I understand the basics of the complex numbers, but I have trouble formulating these kind of proofs. I think $\lambda$ can be written as $\alpha + \beta i$, but what is the next step?

Comment: Do you mean $|\lambda|^2=\lambda\bar\lambda$?

Comment: What is the definition you are using for the modulus of a complex number?

Comment: @Kenta S I changed it, I do.

Comment: The polar form would help too.

Comment: Thanks all, I got to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $|\lambda|^2$.

Once $\lambda=\alpha+\beta i$, use the fact that $|\lambda|=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$ and $\bar{\lambda}=\alpha-\beta i$, then expand.

Comment: Thanks! I got the full proof now!

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to write the RHS in terms of your new notation, namely
$$\lambda\bar{\lambda}=(\alpha+i\beta)(\alpha-i\beta)$$
And then multiply term by term.

Can you take it from here? If you get stuck, comment what you got, I will help you further.

Comment: I got it, thanks!